# Padding for a view is not removed when make the visibility.gone on the widget

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I have a RadioGroup which has three buttons, it has a padding of 16dp, so there is space around the RadioGroup (rgSrCapabilities).
Radio group is inside a constraint layout (clSrrCapabilities)
when I remove the radio group programatically, `clSrrCapabilities.visibility = View.GONE`, the RadioGroup is removed but the padding is not removed I can still see the green corners which is set to rgSrCapabilities

What I want to do it, I want 16dp space around the RadioGroup.
and when I do clSrCapabilities.visibility = View.GONE/ or rgSrCapabilities.visibility = View.GONE, the clSrCapabilities constraint layout should be GONE.

This is the xml for reference

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clSrCapabilities"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white_screen_bg"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clSr" >

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rgSrCapabilities"
                    style="@style/SpinnerRounded"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbPureSr"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/radio_flat_selector"
                        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/sr_only"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/radio_flat_text_selector" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbOff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/radio_flat_selector"
                        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/sr_off"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/radio_flat_text_selector" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbZeroExport"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/radio_flat_selector"
                        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/sr_and_grid"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/radio_flat_text_selector" />

                </RadioGroup>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Images

[image]

when RGgroup is removed

[image]

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Hi i dont really get the question, if you put visibility.GONE to the radiogroup automtatically all the layout is not going to be visibility.GONE ( android:id="@+id/clSrCapabilities" one)
Is what you wanna achive?

Comment: android:background="@color/green" is set to radio group. but when i do rgSrCapabilities.visibility = View.GONE still I see the radioGroup in green

Comment: Did you try set the height and width of radio group to 0dp 0dp so they match constraint?

Comment: @Dak28 when i set height and width of radio group to 0dp, the radio group does not appear, its hidden

Comment: @BRDroid maybe you are misssing constraintBottomToBottomOf="parent"

also try to use "android:margin" instead of "android:padding"